# Unable to read a excel file from sharepoint via Azure data factory

Tags: sharepoint, azure-data-factory

I have an excel file in Sharepoint. I want to read that file and write the contents to a table in Azure SQL via Azure Data Factory.

I have followed the steps in the link below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list?tabs=data-factory

I had done the Prerequisites.
I have also created a Web Activity to get the access token from SharePoint Online successfully.

I am stuck at the last step with the copy activity.

- Created a HTTP linked service with the below base URL
  [https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('xxx/Shared%20Documents')/Test01.xlsx](https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(%27xxx/Shared%20Documents%27)/Test01.xlsx)

[image]

- Created a dataset

[image]

- Created a pipeline with copy activity

[image]

The copy activity is throwing the error below:

> ErrorCode=ExcelUnsupportedFormat,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Only
> '.xls' and '.xlsx' format is supported in reading excel file while
> error is '   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
> includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.MultipartSequentialReadSource.d__5.MoveNext()
> at
> Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.TransferStream.ReadInternal(Byte[]
> buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
> Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.TransferStream.Read(Byte[]
> buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
> ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.Compression.Streams.InflaterInputBuffer.Fill()
> at
> ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.Compression.Streams.InflaterInputBuffer.ReadLeByte()
> at
> ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.Compression.Streams.InflaterInputBuffer.ReadLeInt()
> at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream.GetNextEntry()    at
> NPOI.OpenXml4Net.Util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource..ctor(ZipInputStream
> inp)    at NPOI.OpenXml4Net.OPC.ZipPackage..ctor(Stream filestream,
> PackageAccess access)    at
> NPOI.OpenXml4Net.OPC.OPCPackage.Open(Stream in1)    at
> NPOI.Util.PackageHelper.Open(Stream is1)    at
> NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook..ctor(Stream is1)    at
> Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.ExcelUtility.GetExcelWorkbook(String
> fileExtension, TransferStream
> stream)'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Http
> request failed with status code 401 Unauthorized, usually this is
> caused by invalid credentials, please check your activity settings.
> Request URL:
> https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('xxx/Shared
> Documents')/Test01.xlsx.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The
> remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.,Source=System,'

The file I am trying to read is here:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Unable to read a excel file from sharepoint via Azure data factory

When you use this URL `https://[sharepoint-domain-name].sharepoint.com/sites/[sharepoint-site]/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/[sharepoint-site]/[relative-path-to-file]')/$value`  it will generate or download the fie with name value without extension. this is main reason you are getting **Only '.xls' and '.xlsx' format is supported in reading excel file** this error

So, you can try with the giving sample file name like `sample.xslx` instead of `$value` in URL to get file with proper format.

Or

You can use binary dataset for both source and sink.

- first store the file in blob storage with excel format.
- The use another copy activity to copy that data in Azure SQL database.